# Array does not append more than one object in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to initialize and then append Class object to array through delegate func. Delegate Double comes from button press with some data.

Problem here is that I am trying to show array at TableViewCell, but it doesn't showing at all, I guess main problem is that expensesArray value is 1 and it's not stacking but replacing same array with other value. Will be really happy to hear what you think.

P.S cellForRowAtIndexPath does not getting called.

```
class ExpensesTableViewController: UITableViewController, ExpensesEnteredDelegate{

//MARK : Properties
var expensesArray = [SpendedMoneyObject]()
var delegatedDouble:Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func setExpenses(expensesFromMainView: Double) {

    delegatedDouble = expensesFromMainView
  var  aSpendedMoneyObject = SpendedMoneyObject(moneySpent: delegatedDouble)
    expensesArray.append(aSpendedMoneyObject) 
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return expensesArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier =  "ExpensesCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExpensesTableViewCell
    print("Iam here")
    let expense = expensesArray[indexPath.row]
    let fromDoubleToString = "\(expense.moneySpent)"

    cell.loadItemsToCell(fromDoubleToString, date: expense.date)



    return cell
 }
```

Object class:

```
class SpendedMoneyObject {
var moneySpent: Double
var currentTime = NSDate().toShortTimeString()
var date: String

init(moneySpent: Double) {
    self.date = currentTime
    self.moneySpent = moneySpent

}}
```

Adding Delegate protocol:

```
protocol ExpensesEnteredDelegate {
func setExpenses(expensesFromMainView: Double)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var moneyTextField: UITextField!

var delegate: ExpensesEnteredDelegate? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func spentButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    // Defining ExpensesVC
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newExpensesVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExpensesTableView") as! ExpensesTableViewController
    delegate = newExpensesVC

    // Delegating expenses Double value
    if (delegate != nil) {
       let myDouble = Double(moneyTextField.text!)
        let expenses: Double = myDouble!
        delegate!.setExpenses(expenses)
    }
}}
```

**Edit:** Problem with array was that every time i pressed the button it was creating new VC so i moved it from button func to ViewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Defining ExpensesVC
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newExpensesVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExpensesTableView") as! ExpensesTableViewController
    delegate = newExpensesVC

}
```

Now i have another problem, when i open my TableView view in simulator all arrays value sets to 0. Can't get it why. I am using Tab Bar Controller to get from view to tableView

Comment: Show the code where you call `setExpenses`

Comment: `P.S cellForRowAtIndexPath does not getting called.` Did you set your tableView's dataSource to this object?

Comment: @AyushGoel Not sure, how i can do it?

Comment: @dan i added some more code

Comment: at every button click you re define new `ExpensesTableView`, You must put the definition `newExpensesVC` out side button click

Comment: @wajeeh nice man! but here i have another problem, now array is filling with data but it doesn't showing in tableView. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: try tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @Mehul already did it in setExpenses delegate func, but still nothing is showing in tableView

Comment: Set breakpoints in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Make sure they're getting called after `reloadData()` is called. Also, check that `expensesArray.count` returns the value you expect.

Comment: can you put the full or at least the whole code which contains the problem ?

Comment: @wajeeh it's all here. I just tested that the problem is when i open my TableView view in simulator all arrays value sets to 0. Can't get it why